# How to access field sensitivity and compliance categorization data?

Tags: apex

With [Winter'20 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_dpp_compliance_categorization.htm) we now can specify Compliance Categorization for fields. However, it's not clear if we can access it in apex. [DescribeFieldResult Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) doesn't provide any specific methods to retrieve this info.

Comment: You can retrieve this information using SOAP and/or Tooling API using `FieldSecurityClassification` and `FieldDefinition` respectively. Details on this [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_classification_metadata_fields.htm&type=5). Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use get that data using below SOQL. Please add the fields as you like:

SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Description, BusinessOwnerId, BusinessStatus, SecurityClassification
FROM FieldDefinition
WHERE EntityDefinitionId in ('Account','Lead')

Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_classification_metadata_fields.htm&type=5